# Aligning elements in a flex-row to the right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have the follow that aligns the elements to the right

**HTML**

```
<div class="flex-row">
     <div class="flex-1">
          <button class="el-button el-button--primary">Add File</button>
          <ul class="el-upload">
               <li classs="el-upload">something wider than the button</li>
          </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;

  .flex-1 {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
  }
}
```

But when he the content of the list is wider than the button and it makes something like this:

```
-------
|  X  |
-------
-----------------
|               |
-----------------
```

How do I make it so that it's aligned to the right regardless of the width of the element below? Like this:

```
          -------
          |  X  |
          -------
-----------------
|               |
-----------------
```

Comment: We can't do much without your CSS. As far as I know flex-1 isn't a bootstrap class, is it?

Comment: The classes I used are from Element UI. They come packaged when you declare it's component which then renders the elements. Hence, the button and list. I just added it because I thought it might help (maybe?)

Comment: @SourceOverflow and yeah flex-1 isn't bootstrap. I applied the edit my question makes more sense!

Comment: You need to state what frameworks/technologies you are using in your question. Otherwise, how are we supposed to figure out what is wrong and what you should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bootstrap 4 has many class ready made and also for flexed boxes. See and more https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/ to learn about what is avalaible.

example updating structure with class

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="flex-row ">
     <div class="row justify-content-end">
          <button class="el-button el-button--primary">Add File</button>
          <ul class="el-upload">
               <li classs="el-upload">something wider than the button</li>
          </ul>
     </div>
</div>

or is it about column ?

<div class="flex-row">
     <div class="row flex-column align-items-end">
          <button class="el-button el-button--primary">Add File</button>
          <ul class="el-upload">
               <li classs="el-upload">something wider than the button</li>
          </ul>
     </div>
</div>
</div>
```

to emulate a `flex` container, use a class such as  `.row` , `.d-flex`, see link provided earlier ;) ...

Answer (score -1):

You need to float both elements

This should work

https://codepen.io/dawsonhudson17/pen/GMGPjM

```
<div class="flex-row">
     <div class="flex-1">
          <button style='float: left;'class="el-button el-button--primary">Add File</button>
          <ul class="el-upload">
               <li style='float: left; margin-left: 20px;'classs="el-upload">something wider than the button</li>
          </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

you can also do

```
<li style='float: right;'classs="el-upload">something wider than the button</li>
```